# Not able to download the mongodb dependencies

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Getting the below error tried every command to download the dependency but still not able to download it

[image]

Please refer to the log here. These are the logs for installing mongodb by using the command sudo apt-get install mongodb

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb : Depends: mongodb-server (>= 1:2.4.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
               Conflicts: mongodb but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 mongodb-org-shell : Conflicts: mongodb but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please post the logs from the screenshot as a text.

Comment: @stop-cran. Updated the logs in the problem above

Comment: Follow the instructions in here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ to install MongoDB for Ubuntu